# When using PouchDB is all of the associated remote CouchDB database stored locally?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

When using PouchDB in an App connected to CouchDB on a server does all of the database have to be stored locally in the App and on the server?

I am wanting to create a database with 10's of 1000's of images but only need a few of those images in the App at any one time.

So ideally I want to store the entire database on the CouchDB server and just have PouchDB pull down a few images as and when they are needed to show in the App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on how you use it.

If you just use the remote database, then *nothing* is stored locally.

If you replicate the remote database to your local storage, then you have control over what is replicated by way of [filtered replication](https://pouchdb.com/2015/04/05/filtered-replication.html).

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for.